# Material Design like Search Dialog

Tags: android, search, material-design, search-dialog

There is new Material Designed Gmail app search:

[image]

...after search menu item fired Search Dialog with suggestions accured:

[image]

I am trying to achieve this according to official android developer [guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html)
and now i have this:

[image]

How could i style my Search Dialog in Material Design like style?

Thanks!

Comment: https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/

Comment: @andruboy Thanks for a reply!
Oh! 
<!-- The layout for the search view. Be careful. -->
<item name="layout">...</item>

Comment: And it cause no affect on SearchDialog, just if you are using Search Widget with actionbar